# Submitting the form in WebView - Swift 3.1

Tags: javascript, swift, forms, webview, submit

I was able to fill in the three fields in my webview successfully but couldn't submit the form :

```
   let fillForm = String(format:"document.getElementById('Login').value = '\(login ?? "NA")';document.getElementById('Password').value = '\(password ?? "NA")';document.getElementById('Server').value = '\(server ?? "NA")';")

    WebApp.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: fillForm)

    let Submit = String(format: "document.getElementByvalue('Login').submit()")

    WebApp.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: Submit)
```

I couldn't find an "id" for the Submit button like the others by "inspect element", so i tried to get the element by "value" tag.

input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default"

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

let submit = String(format:"document.forms[0].submit()")